# mosquitto broker shuts down when terminal is closed

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a problem with mosquitto running on my pi 3. I use it to transmit temperature and humidity from several sensors in my appartement (433 mhz) to my node red which is also running on my pi. When I start the broker I can see the messages coming in to my node red but as soon as I close the putty terminal somehow the broker seems to stop transmitting.

My command is this:

```
rtl_433 -F json -M utc | mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.178.37 -t home/rtl_433 -l
```

When I start putty again and want to start the broker again i get the error that the address is already in use.

How can I change this that mosquitto won't stop?
I read something about an autostart feature but there are a lot of possibilities and i am a bit confused which might be the best option for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully someone comes up with a better command line answer for you, but these thoughts are to much to be a comment and is and answer of sorts -

A hack might be to run this within "screen" or "tmux" which will allow you to detach the terminal.

Alternatively   You might be able to convert this to a script by creating a file (eg called rtl2mqtt) with the following

```
  #/bin/bash
  rtl_433 -F json -M utc | mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.178.37 -t home/rtl_433 -l
```

Then run

```
  chmod 755 rtl2mqtt
```

To make it executable.  Lastly, launch it so it goes into the background (note the &) -

```
 rtl2mqtt &
```

I do comment that mosquitto_pub is not a broker, its a client which appears to be pulling data from the rtl433 system and pushing it to mosquitto.  I expect you will find mosquitto running in the background - that is a daemon which is actually the broker.

Comment: thank you very much. I installed screen which also gives me the opportunity to see when something stops the process without setting up a logfile :)